# Contar palabras repetidas de una variable en php

Tags: php

El siguiente script php muestra en pantalla las palabras mas repetidas de una variable en orden de mayor a menor.

```
$text = "Sistema solar es un sistema planetario en que se encuentran la Tierra y otros objetos astronómicos que giran directa o indirectamente en una órbita alrededor de una única estrella conocida como el Sol. La estrella concentra el 99,75 % de la masa del sistema solar. Los cuatro planetas más cercanos, considerablemente más pequeños Mercurio, Venus, Tierra y Marte, también conocidos como los planetas terrestres, están compuestos principalmente por roca y metal.";

    function countLetters($text, $num_return = FALSE, $num_chars = 0, $not_read = array()) {
        preg_match_all('/\b[A-Za-záéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñ]+\b/', $text, $words);
        if (!is_array($not_read)) {
            $not_read = explode(' ', $not_read);
        }
        $words_count = array_count_values(array_filter(array_map('strtolower', $words[0]), function($val) use ($num_chars, $not_read) {
              if (!function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
                return strlen(utf8_decode($val)) >= $num_chars && !in_array($val, $not_read);
              }
              return mb_strlen($val) >= $num_chars && !in_array($val, $not_read);
        }));
        arsort($words_count);
        if ($num_return !== FALSE) return array_slice($words_count, 0, $num_return);
        return $words_count;
    }

print_r(countLetters($text));
```

y me muestra lo siguiente en pantalla:

```
Array ( [sistema] => 3 [y] => 3 [la] => 3 [solar] => 2 [planetas] => 2 [estrella] => 2 [los] => 2 [de] => 2 [una] => 2 [tierra] => 2 [en] => 2 [m�s] => 2 [como] => 2 [que] => 2 [el] => 2 [peque�os] => 1 [considerablemente] => 1 [cercanos] => 1 [cuatro] => 1 [tambi�n] => 1 [principalmente] => 1 [por] => 1 [roca] => 1 [metal] => 1 [compuestos] => 1 [est�n] => 1 [venus] => 1 [marte] => 1 [conocidos] => 1 [terrestres] => 1 [mercurio] => 1 [conocida] => 1 [otros] => 1 [objetos] => 1 [astron�micos] => 1 [encuentran] => 1 [se] => 1 [es] => 1 [un] => 1 [planetario] => 1 [giran] => 1 [directa] => 1 [sol] => 1 [concentra] => 1 [masa] => 1 [nica] => 1 [alrededor] => 1 [o] => 1 [indirectamente] => 1 [rbita] => 1 [del] => 1 )
```

Lo que yo necesito si alguien me puede ayudar es guardar en diferentes variables las palabras repetidas mayores a 2 para utilizarlas luego y saber cuales son.

Si alguien me puede ayudar estaria agradecido.

Comment: Sí tiene 20 palabras con  esa condición, 20 variables no sería muy óptimo, para eso están los array. Sí se centra en algo más compacto como los 3 primeros sería lo más conveniente.

Comment: ok, entiendo y en ese caso como seria, para 3 variables por ejemplo.

Comment: Debe actualizar su pregunta enfocando el resultado esperado.

Comment: ok, voy a realizarlo. muy amable de su parte.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener por ejemplo las tres primeras palabras, podría utilizar [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.list.php) para la desestructuración  de un array. *(desde PHP 7, [] es el equivalente a list())*

Los pasos para llegar al array esperado.

1. Obtener las palabras repetidas mayores a dos, para esto podríamos utilizar [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) para realizar el filtro con la condición deseada.
2. Obtener las claves respectivas, para esto nos puede ayudar [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php), para obtener las palabras.
3. Obtener un array de la longitud deseada con la función [array_pad($array, $tamaño,$vporpordefecto)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-pad.php), puede que le pasemos como tamaño 3 pero el array tenga solo 2 elementos, entonces ese valor que falta lo completará con el tercer parámetro.

   ```
   $array= CountLetters($text);
   [$primera,$segunda,$tercera] = array_pad(array_keys(
                                    array_filter( $array, function ($valor){ return $valor > 2; }
                                )),3,'vacio');

   var_dump($primera,$segunda,$tercera);
   ```

<kbd>[Demo](https://paiza.io/projects/8QcbXvrDz-0lk94YdvdoiA)</kbd>

Comment: lo probe y no logro que me funcione

Comment: @juanpablo añadí un lik demo del funcionamiento.

Comment: ok, lo voy a leer. desde ya garcias por su tiempo.